# How to set Crystal Reports as the default for opening .rpt files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am new in handling Crystal Reports.

I'm using Crystal Reports 2011(Version=13.0.2000.0) and want to open .rpt files with Crystal Report as the default application.When right-click the .rpt file have 2 options, **Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector, and Choose Program**.When I select Choose Program, then click the Browse button, Crystal Reports is not available as one of the programs to choose.When I look at the programs available via the Control Panel, I see **SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Visual Studio v13.0.2000.0**, but I'm not able to select it as the default for opening .rpt files.I'm assuming the program file is in my Program Files folder somewhere in the Business Objects folder, but I'm not sure which file I need to set Crystal as the default program. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using CR 2013 and Windows 7, we have to

1. "Open With..."
2. to this path **C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Crystal Reports 13** or : **C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XIII 4.0**

then **crw32.exe**

Comment: Jassim, I tried this earlier.But no such exe file is found.                               I checked in my folder C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Also inside C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and eventually found the crw32.exe file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86 then click on the .exe file.